# Face Recognition with EmguCV 2.4 returns NULL

Tags: emgucv, face-recognition

I used the Face Recognition class with EmguCV version 2.2 and everything worked fine.
I just recently upgraded to the 2.4 version.

I start by creating a Recognizer class.

```
_recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(_trainingImages.ToArray(), _nameList.ToArray(), ref _terminationCriteria);
```

Now I want to get a result for my picture with

```
EigenObjectRecognizer.RecognitionResult fN = _recognizer.Recognize(face);
```

but the RecognitionResult is always null.

EDIT: It works using an eigenDistanceThreshold of 5000.